# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated turn off my background music

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

i have background music when the view is open then the music is start to play perfectly without error even if i switch view to other view and go back again to main view, background music is still playing without problem. but when i change my code in back button from

```
mainViewController *mainView =[[mainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
mainView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:mainView animated:YES]; // this will flip from right
```

to

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // this will flip back from left
```

when is flip back to main menu, my background music is not playing. just curious why? how to fix it? for some reason why i change the code to     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; because i want my view flip back from other way.

my background music is playing when mainView is show using this code

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *pathFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Start" ofType:@"mp3"];
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathFile] error:NULL];
        [player play];
    }
```

Stop if view is change

```
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [player stop];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start you player in ViewDidApper method. Hope it will help you

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSString *pathFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Start" ofType:@"mp3"];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathFile] error:NULL];
    [player play];
[super viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

Comment: i've tried it before, the result is same. wont play. just curious why?